# Bootstrap Modal popup with Spring MVC and jQuery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

In my app developing (made with Spring Boot, Bootstrap, jQuery and jdbcTemplate), I have some results to show after querying a form into table format and to achieve this I used jQuery DataTable. All works perfectly.

The next task is to add a column on the table with a button to edit some fields; for example, for the Events data, clicking the button it must be possible modify 2 values, note and status.

To perform this, I used Bootstrap modal (for the first time, I am a newbie with this tool) into the js file with the DataTable code.

This is the code of the js file:

```
var DTevents = false;
$(document).ready(function() {  

    DTevents = $('#eventsdata').DataTable( 
            { 
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax":{
                            url: "../getevents.json",
                            type: "post",
                            "data": function (d)
                            {
                                d = $.extend(d, {statusname :  $('#statusname').val()}, {typename :  $('#typename').val()}, {infoname :  $('#infoname').val()},
                                                {notename :  $('#notename').val()}, {idname :  $('#idname').val()}, {username :  $('#username').val()}, 
                                                {hostname :  $('#hostname').val()});
                            }
                            
                       },
                "columns":  [
                    { "data": "date" },
                    { "data": "type" },
                    { "data": "name" },
                    { "data": "user_name" },
                    { "data": "status" },
                    { "data": "closing_date" },
                    { "data": "info" },
                    { "data": "note" },
                    { "render": function(o){
                        return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit</button>' +
                        '<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">' +
                        '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
                        '<div class="modal-content">' +
                              '<div class="modal-header">' +
                                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>' +
                                '<h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>' +
                              '</div>' +
                              '<div class="modal-body">' +
                              '<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">' +
                              '<div class="form-group">' +
                                '<label  class="col-sm-2 control-label"' +
                                          'for="inputNotes">Notes</label>' +
                                '<div class="col-sm-10">' +
                                    '<input type="text" class="form-control"' + 
                                    'id="newnote" placeholder="Put here the note"/>' +
                                '</div>' +
                              '</div>' +
                              '<div class="form-group">' +
                                '<label for = "type" class = "col-sm-2 control-label">Status</label>' +
                             '<div class = "col-sm-10">' +
                            '<select class = "form-control" id = "typename" name="type options">' +
                            '<option value="open">open</option>' +
                                '<option value="closed">closed</option>' +
                            '</select>' +
                         '</div>' +
                              '</div>' +
                            '</form>' +
                            '</div>'  +
                              '</div>' +
                              '<div class="modal-footer">' +
                                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>' +
                                '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>' +
                              '</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                          '</div>' +
                        '</div>';
                    } }
                ]
            } );
    } );
```

With this code, if I query the form, for example on the os type, I obtain this output:

Table results:
[image]

Popup results:
[image]

As you can see, I obtain a pop up with form editing. And it's ok. So, what's the problem?

1. It's horrible, for me, put the code of the Modals directly inside the js file of data table; I would like to have an external file to import/include into this js file. Is it possible to achieve this?
2. This form is an "empty" form; I mean that it is no truly interactive. If I click the save button, no modify are made; I made the DAO and the controller Spring mvc, so I must "link" the form to this.
   In the rest of my project I perform easily this, because I use the jsp file; but this form, of course, is NOT on a jsp file. So, my question is: if I put the code of Modal inside a jsp file, can I use this file inside the js file of DataTable?And if not, how can I make this form truly interactive?

UPDATE: after responses below, I modified my code in this way:

(from data columns)

```
{ "render": function ( data, type, full) {
                        
                        return '<a class="btn btn-info btn-md">' + 'Edit' + '</a>';
                    }
                  }
```

(function for events handling, where `#mymodal` is the id of the modal, defined in another jsp. NOTE: for now I have not implemented the data logic and the sending to controllers, because I want before be sure that the pop up is opened)

```
$("#eventsdata").on("click", ".btn btn-info btn-sm", function () {
    var html = "/jsp/editbutton.jsp";
    $("#eventsdata").load(html);
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
});
```

The editbutton.jsp is the file where i put the modal code and is under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp`

However, my code does not work; no pop up modal is opened. I can see the button but if I click, nothing happens. What I wrong?

EDIT2: founded. The problem was double: the code of the function "on" was OUTSIDE the ready document; and the button class must be, always inside the on function, not:

```
".btn btn-info btn-sm"
```

but

```
".btn.btn-info.btn-md"
```

EDIT3: the code is now this:

var DTevents = false;
$(document).ready(function() {

```
DTevents = $('#eventsdata').DataTable( 
        { 
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax":{
                        url: "../getevents.json",
                        type: "post",
                        "data": function (d)
                        {
                            d = $.extend(d, {statusname :  $('#statusname').val()}, {typename :  $('#typename').val()}, {infoname :  $('#infoname').val()},
                                            {notename :  $('#notename').val()}, {idname :  $('#idname').val()}, {username :  $('#username').val()}, 
                                            {hostname :  $('#hostname').val()});
                        }
                        
                   },
            "columns":  [
                { "data": "date" },
                { "data": "type" },
                { "data": "name" },
                { "data": "user_name" },
                { "data": "status" },
                { "data": "closing_date" },
                { "data": "info" },
                { "data": "note" },
                { "render": function ( data, type, full, meta) {
                    
                        return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-md' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'> Edit </button>";
                }
              }
            ]
        } );
```

} );

The actual problem is that, both two modal show solution (using the jQuery function `.on("click")` and the one used in the code, `data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'`) don't solve the main problem: how may I load the external jsp with the modal code?

The problem, more specifically, is not what use (I suppose I may use the jQuery load function) but where use it.
For example, if I use on `#eventsdata` (that is the id of the page with table heading and on which I use Data Table), in have (of course) the substitution of table data with something else and this is not the modal, because I got a blank page).

Comment: If someone has this problem maybe they could solve it with other approach like explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70100248/get-data-from-thymeleaf-to-a-modal-bootstrap-jquery/70107604#70107604

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should load

```
    "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
          return <button type="button" id="modal_ +'+data.id+' " class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit</button>';
       ....................
   }
```

and do ajax to load data for this button specific with `id=modal_1`
You can cut this string to get id of data

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom button and add event to it like this

```
"render": function(data, type, full) {
    var str = "";
    if(data != null){
        str = "<input type='button' class='clsGuidelines'  value='View' />";
    }
    return str;
}
```

Event Handler:

```
$("#eventsdata").on("click", ".clsGuidelines", function () {

    var iPos = $(this).closest("tr").index();
    var aData = $("#eventsdata").DataTable().fnGetData( iPos ); //get data of the clicked row
    // aData has all values for clicked row 
   // Open dialog or Modal here 
   // you can load your JSP page here and continue 


});
```

Comment: Uhm, interesting; but I don't understand one thing:  why in the var aData we have  $("#tblDosageList")? What is it tblDosageList?

Comment: Just a sample id in your case it should be eventsdata .. edited check...